# How to use JavaScript with Ajax Page Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I ma trying to create a page so when i click a buttin to view more it will pop up and load using ajax the page. But the current problem is the page works fine when not using ajax but when i try to use ajax the javascript on the page does not run,

This is my current code for ajax call:

```
<script>
  function leftmyFunction<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $row_rs_GET_stats_champs1['Champion']).''.$row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Role'];?>() {
    document.getElementById("leftmorestats<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $row_rs_GET_stats_champs1['Champion']).''.$row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Role']; ?>").classList.toggle("show");

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("leftmorestats<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $row_rs_GET_stats_champs1['Champion']).''.$row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Role']; ?>").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    }

    <?php if($row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2'] == $thispageschampionID) { ?>
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "getchampiongraphdatabronze.php?Champion=<?php echo $thispageschampion; ?>&Championsec=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_stats_champs1['Champion']; ?>&Role=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Role']; ?>&Champ_2_winrate=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_winrate']; ?>&Champ_2_Kills=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_Kills']; ?>&Champ_2_Deaths=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_Deaths']; ?>&Champ_2_assists=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_assists']; ?>&Champ_2_minionsKilled=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_minionsKilled']; ?>&Champ_2_goldEarned=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_goldEarned']; ?>&Champ_2_totalDamageDealtToChampions=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_totalDamageDealtToChampions']; ?>&Champ_1_winrate=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_winrate']; ?>&Champ_1_Kills=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_Kills']; ?>&Champ_1_Deaths=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_Deaths']; ?>&Champ_1_assists=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_assists']; ?>&Champ_1_minionsKilled=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_minionsKilled']; ?>&Champ_1_goldEarned=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_goldEarned']; ?>&Champ_1_totalDamageDealtToChampions=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_totalDamageDealtToChampions']; ?>",true);
    <?php } else { ?>
      xmlhttp.open("GET","getchampiongraphdatabronze.php?Champion=<?php echo $thispageschampion; ?>&Championsec=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_stats_champs1['Champion']; ?>&Role=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Role']; ?>&Champ_2_winrate=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_winrate']; ?>&Champ_2_Kills=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_Kills']; ?>&Champ_2_Deaths=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_Deaths']; ?>&Champ_2_assists=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_assists']; ?>&Champ_2_minionsKilled=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_minionsKilled']; ?>&Champ_2_goldEarned=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_goldEarned']; ?>&Champ_2_totalDamageDealtToChampions=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_1_totalDamageDealtToChampions']; ?>&Champ_1_winrate=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_winrate']; ?>&Champ_1_Kills=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_Kills']; ?>&Champ_1_Deaths=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_Deaths']; ?>&Champ_1_assists=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_assists']; ?>&Champ_1_minionsKilled=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_minionsKilled']; ?>&Champ_1_goldEarned=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_goldEarned']; ?>&Champ_1_totalDamageDealtToChampions=<?php echo $row_rs_GET_tats_champs['Champ_2_totalDamageDealtToChampions']; ?>",true);
    <?php } ?>

    xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

It works to load the parts of the page that are not using JavaScript but the parts that us JavaScript wont load.

How can I make it load all the javascript?

This is the page im trying to load

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<?php


$championsmainname = $_GET['Champion'];
$championssecname = $_GET['Championsec'];
$championsmainrole = $_GET['Role'];
$champions2winrate = $_GET['Champ_2_winrate'];
$champions2kills = $_GET['Champ_2_Kills'];
$champions2deaths = $_GET['Champ_2_Deaths'];
$champions2assists = $_GET['Champ_2_assists'];
$champions2minionskilled = $_GET['Champ_2_minionsKilled'];
$champions2goldearned = $_GET['Champ_2_goldEarned'];
$champions2totaldamagedealt = $_GET['Champ_2_totalDamageDealtToChampions'];
$champions1winrate = $_GET['Champ_1_winrate'];
$champions1kills = $_GET['Champ_1_Kills'];
$champions1deaths = $_GET['Champ_1_Deaths'];
$champions1assists = $_GET['Champ_1_assists'];
$champions1minionskilled = $_GET['Champ_1_minionsKilled'];
$champions1goldearned = $_GET['Champ_1_goldEarned'];
$champions1totaldamagedealt = $_GET['Champ_1_totalDamageDealtToChampions'];

?>


<p style="
font-size: 19px;
font-weight: 600;
color: #CBCBCB;
font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;">Matchup Performance</p>

<div id="leftshowchampiondatascript<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $championssecname).''.$championsmainrole; ?>" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 450px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>


                        Highcharts.chart('leftshowchampiondatascript<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $championssecname).''.$championsmainrole; ?>', {

chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'area',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',



},

exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            enabled: false
        }    
    }
},

 legend: {
        itemStyle: {
            color: '#c4c4c4',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    },

credits: {
  enabled: false
},


title: {
style: {
    display: 'none'
}
},


plotOptions: {
    series: {
        lineColor: '#808080'
    }
},


pane: {
    size: '80%',


},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Win Rate', 'Kills', 'Deaths', 'Assists',
            'Minions Killed', 'Gold Earned', 'Damage Dealt'],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0,
    gridLineColor: "#808080",
    gridLineDashStyle: "Solid",
    gridLineWidth: 2,
    labels: {
     style: {
        color: '#c4c4c4',
        font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
     }
  }
 },

yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0,
    gridLineColor: "#808080",
    gridLineDashStyle: "Solid",
    gridLineWidth: 2,
    labels: {
     style: {
        color: '#c4c4c4',
        font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
     }
  }
  },

tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
},


series: [{
    name: '<?php echo $championsmainname; ?>',
    color: 'rgba(184, 70, 70, 0.7)',
    data: [<?php echo $champions2winrate*100; ?>, <?php echo $champions2kills; ?>, <?php echo $champions2deaths; ?>, <?php echo $champions2assists; ?>, <?php echo $champions2minionskilled; ?>, <?php echo $champions2goldearned; ?>, <?php echo $champions2totaldamagedealt; ?>],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
}, {
    name: '<?php echo $championssecname; ?>',
    color: 'rgba(85, 184, 70, 0.5)',
    data: [<?php echo $champions1winrate*100; ?>, <?php echo $champions1kills; ?>, <?php echo $champions1deaths; ?>, <?php echo $champions1assists; ?>, <?php echo $champions1minionskilled; ?>, <?php echo $champions1goldearned; ?>, <?php echo $champions1totaldamagedealt; ?>],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
}]

});

                        </script>
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, "...load all the javascript"? Do you mean the `xmlhttp.open()` does not seem to make a call to the provided URL?

Comment: If you open the console, does it list any errors?  Usually, when added code causes javaScript not to work, it's because there's an error in that code (usually a missing closing parentheses or curly brace) that will be noted in the console.

Comment: I get no error just highcharts javascript wont run when called via ajax like i done aboved. html shows just not javascript

Comment: I have added the file i am trying to run with ajax i think the problem is to do with it getting.

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>